# Inverting a sentence which includes 'never ever'

Tags: inversion

**Never will I ever take up smoking**.

The test asks (not a homework) if it is correct or incorrect; I circled 'incorrect' but according to the answer key, it is correctly inverted.

Wouldn't the original sentence be 'I will never ever take up smoking'? If so, I think the adverbial is 'never ever' and I thought the inversion should be 'Never ever will I take up smoking'. How does the correct answer is correct?

The test is on [this website](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/course/towards-advanced/unit-25/session-1)

Comment: What test? Who wrote it?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your inversion  "Never ever will I take up smoking" and the version in the test "Never will I ever take up smoking" are possible.   They both have a negative adverb and an inverted verb-subject.

The second is more formal, the first is slightly childish.  The function of the word "ever" is to intensify the adverb "never", but it is not part of the adverb.

Comment: "Never, ever, will I make this mistake again" Trip Advisor review of Egyptian hotel.